# sqlite3 type TEXT input error

Tags: python, sqlite

So i have a sqlite3 Database and created a table with two values.
This is the code that created the table.

```
CREATE TABLE `ip` (
    `PID`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `IP`    TEXT
 );
```

Now i have python script in which I can enter an IP address and stores this in the database.
But when i write to the field IP the value 1.2.3.4 i get an error in python:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".3": syntax error.
```

This is the python code:

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('reverseDNS.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO ip (ip) VALUES (1.2.3.4)"

cursor.execute(sql)
connection.commit()



sql = 'SELECT * FROM ip'
cursor.execute(sql)
rows = cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)

connection.close()
```

Any idea how to store an IP address in sqlite3

I have tried other types, like integer but this has the same error

Comment: Show your Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the value of the `ip` column is defined as `TEXT`, literal values are required to be enclosed in single quotes. You should find that the query

```
sql = "INSERT INTO ip (ip) VALUES ('1.2.3.4')"
```

works as you expect.

Comment: Right you are. thanks. I thought it would already be a string in sql format.

Comment: You may have seen parameterised queries (the safest way to introduce variable values into your SQL queries). Then the data value is represented in the query by a simple questions mark, and data is provided as a tuple passed to the `execute` method. So you might have written `addr = '1.2.3.4'` followed by `sql = "INSERT INTO ip (ip) VALUES (?)"` and finally `cursor.execute(sql, (addr, ))`